# How to update UI in Vue.js immediately after creation of table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple component that calls to a database, retrieves a list of tables and creates a new one when the user clicks a button. My fuctionality currently works, the only problem is that I have to reload the page in order to see the list of updated tables and I want the newly created table to display instantly after the user has created it, how can I achieve this? Here is my attempt:

```
<md-button class="view-captable-btn" v-for="item in capTables" :key="item.contractAddress">
  <p>{{item.label}}</p>
  <p class="contract-address-p"> {{item.contractAddress}}</p>
</md-button>

<md-dialog-actions>
  <md-button class="close-btn" @click="showDialog = false"><span class="close-btn-span">Cancel</span></md-button>
  <md-button class="create-cap-table-btn" @click="showDialog = false; createNewCapTable()"><span class="add-captable-span">Add new cap table</span></md-button>
</md-dialog-actions>
```

```
data() {
    const apiKey = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ADMIN_KEY;
    
      return {
          showDialog: false,
          createNewShareholderDialog: false,
          services: new this.$service(apiKey),
          capTables: null,
          initialPoolOptions: ''
      }
  },
  methods: {
      async createNewCapTable() {
        let label = this.$refs.form.platformName.value
        let poolSize = this.$refs.form.poolSize.value
        let res = await this.services.deployStockCapTable('http://vue.js', poolSize, label)
        console.log(res)
      }, 

      logout() {
      this.$router.push('/')
      },

      async readDeployedCapTables() {
         let res = await this.services.readAllStockCapTables();
         this.capTables = res
      },
  },
    mounted() {
      this.readDeployedCapTables()
    },
     created() {
     document.body.style.background = '#e5e5e5';
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.body.style.background = 'white';
  },
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push the `res` into the source of `v-for` i.e. `capTables`

```
    async createNewCapTable() {
       let label = this.$refs.form.platformName.value
       let poolSize = this.$refs.form.poolSize.value
       let res = await this.services.deployStockCapTable('http://vue.js', poolSize, label)
       console.log(res)
       this.capTables.push(res) // <- this line 
    },
```

Comment: Tried it, newly added table is still visible only after refresh.